# is such in the database - 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysqli

it is such that I have trouble lying 2 inputs together in a and after just it into the database

the problem is when it comes to the database looks like this **0000-00-00 00:00:00**

this is how I have chosen to keep the date and time apart to make it simple as possible.

```
function tilmeldAdmin()
{
    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `tilmeldt` (`title`, `info`, `Dato`,  `antal`, `opret_navn`, `opret_email`, `opret_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('sssissi', $title, $info, $Dato, $antal, $opret_navn, $opret_email, $opret_id);
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $info = $_POST["info"];
        $Dato = $_POST["dob"] . $_POST["time"];//Here is error when it should be entered into the database (Everything else works just fine with no problems)
        $antal = $_POST["antal"];
        $opret_navn = $_SESSION["navn"];
        $opret_email = $_SESSION["mail"];
        $opret_id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does $_POST["dob"] & $_POST["time"] look like?

Comment: probably, you forgot to put the space between date and time. Try `$_POST["dob"] . ' ' . $_POST["time"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are getting the date in YYYY-mm-dd format and the time in HH:ii:ss your issues is you are missing a space between the two elements.

```
$Dato = $_POST["dob"] .' '. $_POST["time"];
```

If you are being provided the date in a relatively sane manner you can use strtotime to get the date in the format you want.

```
$Dato = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST["dob"]." ".$_POST["time"]));
```

Comment: i take `$Dato = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST["dob"]." ".$_POST["time"]));` and it works 100% Thanks for help!!